# Active Admin and lightbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a problem with lightbox, when I set the attribute data-lightbox, no info is displayed in the tag, just have href attribute

```
  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :validate_by_us
    column :resource
    column "Photo" do |photo|
      link_to image_tag(photo.photo_url), image_path(photo.photo_url), :data => { lightbox: photo.photo_url}
    end
    actions
  end
```